# Karate DSL variable is not resolved in array initialization

Tags: karate

In my karate feature I want to initialize an array with a variable in it.

To my understanding, that should be possible with a single line like this: `* def array = [Id]`

However, that sets the variable `array` to `["Id"]`. But using set works.

See example:

```
  Scenario: WTF
    * def Id = 123
    * print "Id", Id
    * print "[Id]", [Id]
    * def array = [Id]
    * print "array", array
    * set array[0] = Id
    * print "array", array
```

Produces the output

```
Id 123 
[Id] [123]
array ["Id"]
array [123]
```

How can `* def array = [Id]` be changed to produce the array with the variable in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Scenario: FTW
* def id = 123

# karate recommended
* def array = [ '#(id)' ]
* match array == [123]

# js developers like this
* def array = ([id])
* match array == [123]
```

And please read this for a full explanation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#enclosed-javascript